# want to remove duplicated rows, but all rows are removed

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicated rows in a data frame.

```
df<-df[-which(duplicated(df[c("type")])),]
```

column "type" class is character.
Definitely there are unique values, but all rows are deleted.

```
nrow(unique(df$type))
```

It says 'NULL'.

What's possible problem?

Comment: `unique(df$type)` returns a character vector. It does not have `nrow` value. You should check it's `length` i.e `length(unique(df$type))`. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duplicated` return a TRUE/FALSE vector, so in this case you don't need the  `which` function.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0), y = c(2,1,0,0))
df

#   x y
# 1 0 2
# 2 1 1
# 3 1 0
# 4 0 0

!duplicated(df$x,)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

df <- df[ !duplicated( df$x ) ,]
df

#   x y
# 1 0 2
# 2 1 1
```